# Prevent 300ms delay on Touch-Devices

Tags: javascript, ios, web-applications, touch

There is this built-in delay of 300ms on Android & iOS-devices to capture double-clicks (who uses that on website anyway, speaking of UX?!)
I'd like to get rid of that delay & read a lot about the topic but still don't get it why this simple code is not "OK" or would break the UX:

```
$('a').bind('touchend', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.click();
});
```

For me, it seems to work perfect but I'm sure there are reasons why this shouldn't be done like that. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: I would like to point you to http://ftlabs.github.io/fastclick/ that handle this issue correctly

Comment: thanks - but there I read: "Internally, FastClick uses document.createEvent to fire a synthetic click event as soon as touchend is fired by the browser. It then suppresses the additional click event created by the browser after that." - so what is the actual benefit or difference to my code-example?

Comment: is your solution working on different platform / version?

Comment: Remember that on iOS (maybe Android too), a double-tap is used to zoom the page. Users expect that. Also you should make sure that your code produces no unexpected behaviour with scrolling / dragging events, or long-taps (which usually display a context menu allowing actions like "open in background"). Finally, test your site with accessibility features enabled. A single-tap selects and a double-tap (anywhere on the page) activates when voiceover is enabled, although your page will probably never see the raw taps in that case.

Comment: @Dave you have some valid points there, I agree. However, zooming is totally disable on that page, it's a responsive site and it's displayed perfectly with zoom = 1. I will have to look into scrolling / dragging, thanks. Accessibility is a problem, that's true, but none of the (heavy) frameworks for disabling the delay take care of that, how could they? If you want to act directly on the first click, there's no possiblity for a double-click, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer:** A `click` (in mobile) expects you start in the same place you end. A `touchend` lets you start from anywhere.

Now [fastclick](http://ftlabs.github.io/fastclick/) and other libraries seems to handle things other than just links, such as button clicks, form interactions, etc. So there's probably some edge cases you'll be missing as well.

But as for *"bang for your buck"* your thing works great ;-)

Answer (score 7):

That simple code says that when the touch (drag) event ends over a link, trigger event "click" on that link. If the users drags his finger on the screen to scroll the page and such a drag ends over a link, the link will be accidentally triggered. That would break the user experience (UX).

The standard method for removing the delay is to use CSS [`touch-action`](http://caniuse.com/#search=touch-action) property. As I'm writing this, it is still not supported by default in Firefox (`about:config` has flag [`layout.css.touch_action.enabled` which is false by default](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=960316)) and Safari still does not support this at all. MSIE, Chrome and Android browser all support this already on all platforms.

In short:

```
/* Disable double-click to zoom on links, input fields
   and buttons to improve responsiveness */
a, input, button
{
    touch-action: manipulation;
}
```